# Why did git (bash) insert a bunch of nonsense into my new files?

Tags: git, github, git-bash

So. I added some new files to a git repository that I hadn't touched in a couple months. For *some reason*, after merging, pulling and pushing my changes to github, I noticed that all the new files had text inserted into them like this:

```
>>>>>>>>
HEAD
c0d3234k2jl423;lk4j232;l34jk32;l23j4
```

Those *sorts of lines* were inserted sort of randomly but perhaps not entirely randomly throughout the newly added files. Fortunately, there weren't too many new files and I was able to go through, clean them out fairly easily, then re- add / commit / push, and now I believe the problem is behind me.

But what was going on?  I'm still pretty new to git and github.  How can I avoid this happening in the future?  I was using the git bash console on Windows XP.

Also - since this might be related - when I tried committing files earlier via my PHPStorm CLI interface, I would hit "commit" and the commit would never complete.  Just kept trying and trying. So I kept having to abort that command, then go in and manually delete the index.lock file, as well as a COMMIT_EDITMSG.swp file.

Also, this last time (when the nonsense was inserted), I got an error message that said

```
E138: can't write viminfo file u:_viminfo!
Press enter or type command to continue
```

Perhaps that is related as well?  Like I said, the problem seems to be behind me for now, just wondering what went wrong and how to avoid it in the future.

Comment: er, well, `<<<` `===` `>>>` indicates a conflict during a merge.  does `git blame` or `git log` indicate where the edits may have come from?

Comment: Why yes in fact, `git log` does show that there were conflicts in all of the files where the nonsense was found. Thank you. 

There are apparently some fundamental things that I don't understand about git. Like, I wasn't even trying to merge - just to push my changes. Then it _forced_ me to merge (now that I recall ... ) and I don't really understand why. I am the only one working on this project so I'm always on the master branch, or so I thought. What git saw as "conflicts" were what I saw as normal updates.

Comment: @patricksayshi That marks were not invented by git, but only used by it. Don't know, where it originally comes from, but at least nearly every diff-/merge-tool understands them. Try an IDE :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is too long for a comment, so:

You *always* have to merge (or do *something*) if you've made some commits and the remote has *different* commits.  You can only push if it would result in *only* adding new commits on top of what the remote already has.  (This is called a "fast-forward".)

It's only you, so the remote shouldn't have different commits.  But if you've been pulling shenanigans like `rebase` or force-pushing without understanding what you're doing, you might have created the delightfully absurd situation of merging a branch into itself.

So, here is a crash course with one of those commit graph diagrams you will learn to hate:

```
         H <- merge
        / \
you -> G   E <- github
       |   |
       F   D
        \ /
         C
         |
         B
         |
         A
```

This is what commit history might look like if you did work up to C, then someone else (or you on another computer) added D and E and pushed them, and then you started working from C again and did F and G.  You can't push like this, because your local branch doesn't know anything about `D` and `E` or how they relate to history; you only have `A-B-C-F-G`.

But if you merge first to create `H`, you now have a branch with *all* the commits from both you and github on it, and github can be updated merely by "moving" its arrow upwards.  You can't do this work on the remote because it involves changing your files to create merged versions, and the remote machine doesn't actually have physical copies of your files.  (Plus, you'd have no way of resolving conflicts.)

`git log --graph --oneline --decorate` is a pretty useful view that should
show you what you were merging with.  The above diagram will come out looking
like this:

```
* H (master)
|\
*| G
*| F
|* E (origin/master)
|* D
|/
* C
* B
* A
```

git will tell you if there are conflicts after a merge, and `git status` (which you should run *religiously*) will always show conflicting files in scary red.  When this happens, git has almost certainly injected conflict markers into those files, and you need to resolve the problem and finish the merge.  (git will tell you how to finish the merge when it tells you there's a conflict.)

If the stuff between the conflict markers was truly garbage, it's possible your IDE screwed up and corrupted the files.  git is pretty solid and should never destroy data (unless you inadvertently ask it to, of course).

Comment: Thank you, this is incredibly helpful. Some background: yes, now that I recall, the last time I was working on this project I was working _from home_. It was just so long ago I didn't remember. My IDE didn't do anything wrong - the stuff between the conflict markers was apparently code from _both_ the new version and the old one. So rather than resolving the conflict I basically had just told git "keep them both here side by side." I didn't notice this at first because I was more worried at the time about getting the conflict markers out and making the red squiqqly lines go away.

Comment: yep.  on small teams i'll regularly and blindly fire off `git pull --ff-only origin master` (fast-forward only) to only update my `master` if it _won't_ require a merge.  if that fails, it gives me a chance to look at where history diverged before deciding what i want to do; merging in the middle of working on a feature is kind of annoying.  for you, it would let you know you might have made a mistake, since you should never have commits on github you don't already know about.  in larger projects you'd get into "feature branches" and maybe rebasing to insulate you from others' work

Comment: Thanks. I deleted the comment you replied to because I started thinking I was being too much of a pest. But then you replied to it - so you went above and beyond! For the readers of posterity, I had basically asked "So what do devs in professional shops do? Start every work session with `git pull origin master` or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Next time, try using a tool for resolving the conflicts, for example `git mergetool -t kdiff3`. It's fairly fast-forward and intuitive, helps alot when there's loads of small conflicts.

Visual [instructions](http://www.gitguys.com/topics/merging-with-a-gui/) for kdiff3.