# Why does Git put random letters in my files?

Tags: git

I'm trying to host a Discord bot on a Raspberry Pi running Ubuntu Server. I am trying to give it updates by uploading the files to a GitHub repository (public) and then having the Raspberry Pi pull the changes. I take these steps firstL

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "test"
git branch -M master
git remote add origin (MY_PUBLIC_REPO_LINK)
git push origin master
```

That's all fine. Then I run my Jishaku pull command... and it gives me this error:

```
[stderr] warning: Pulling without specifying how to reconcile divergent branches is
[stderr] discouraged. You can squelch this message by running one of the following
[stderr] commands sometime before your next pull:
[stderr] 
[stderr]   git config pull.rebase false  # merge (the default strategy)
[stderr]   git config pull.rebase true   # rebase
[stderr]   git config pull.ff only       # fast-forward only
[stderr] 
[stderr] You can replace "git config" with "git config --global" to set a default
[stderr] preference for all repositories. You can also pass --rebase, --no-rebase,
[stderr] or --ff-only on the command line to override the configured default per
[stderr] invocation.
```

I Google it, they tell me to use the ff-only flag. Okay. Then, I run the command once more, and this error occurs:

```
[stderr] From https://github.com/ConchDev/ConchBot
[stderr]  * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
[stderr] fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories

[status] Return code 128
```

This is where the problems start. If I use the force merge unrelated histories flag, I get things like this at the bottom of my files:

```
>>>>>>> 699b4f2ba544a5047f22ba6a42b2df5d79635eb4
```

It puts that at the end of *every* one of my files, raising syntax errors and refusing to start the program. I have no clue how to solve this and me and my friend have been looking for solutions for a while. Can anyone here help?

Comment: Maybe this can answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14511137/why-did-git-bash-insert-a-bunch-of-nonsense-into-my-new-files

Comment: It sounds like you created a new repository (with `git init`) and then made it use some existing repository as a remote.  Why didn't you make a copy of the existing repository with `git clone` instead?  You explicitly created a new repository with unrelated history to the existing one, so you shouldn't be surprised that you get "unrelated history nonsense", and then when you force a merge, you get conflict markers in your repository files.